# Why does keycloak.resource not require the ClientId of a registered client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, keycloak

I use Keycloak and I configure it with my application.properties file.

```
# Keycloak config (instead of keycloak.json)
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.realm=demo
keycloak.resource=DemoApplication
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.bearer-only=true
```

This works just fine. The problem is that I expected to create a Client in my keycloak admin console for the raealm that is used as keycloak resource.

The docs say

```
resource

    The client-id of the application. Each application has a client-id that is used to identify the application. This is REQUIRED.
```

But in this example DemoApplication is not registred in keycloak. As I understsand, every Application that includes the keycloak-adapter dependency exchanges the public key with keycloak on startup to be able to verify the signature of an incoming token. But why is this working if the client is not registered in keycloak?

Comment: How do you know if this is working correctly ?

Comment: Because the flow works. I get an unauthorized when I call the service api directly. When I have a token I created with a public client, it works as expected.